# MikTeX 2.8, WinEdt 5.4, Adobe Acrobat X

Tags: winedt, acrobat

I am using MikTeX 2.8, WinEdt 5.4 and Acrobat X, and `pdftexify` always produces an error, even though the pdf document is actually produced: it opens up a document in WinEdt called "Acrobat OpenDoc.edt" and displays a warning:

> "Cannot Open DDD Link to: "C ... Acrobat.exe" Service: acroview Topic:
>   control DDEOpen(%$("AcroRead"),"acroview","control");

Help, anyone?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Actual version of MiKTeX is 2.9, the actual version of WinEdt is 7.0. I suggest you update your system ...

Comment: ... and of Adobe Reader it is 10.1.4 ("WinEdt" suggested that you are using `AcroRd32.exe` or `AcroRd64.exe`).

Comment: @Stephen: I’ve downloaded yesterday Adobe Reader XI (forgot to install, though).

Answer (score 3):

Adobe is not designed to work with winedt. Adding to the pain, the DDE controls of Adobe keep changing with its versions. For more details you may refer to  [winedt mailing list](http://winedt.com/support.html).

A solution will be to use a friendly reader like [sumatrapdf](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/download-free-pdf-viewer.html) which works well with winedt (in forward and reverse search). It doesn't lock the opened files like adobe reader.

Answer (score 1):

For Acrobat and Reader X Adobe changed the names of the DDE servers, see [Big Changes in the DDE Naming Convention for Acrobat X](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/2011/01/big-changes-in-the-dde-naming-convention-for-acrobat-x.html). I’m not a WinEdt user, so I don’t know, whether there are other problems, but Harish pointed you to the appropriate mailing list.

For Adobe Reader XI the DDE server name must be changed again according to the linked blog entry, see also [pdfopen / pdfclose don't work with Acrobat/Adobe Reader XI](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85867/pdfopen-pdfclose-dont-work-with-acrobat-adobe-reader-xi).