# pdfopen / pdfclose don't work with Acrobat/Adobe Reader XI

Tags: windows, winedt, acrobat

Can anybody explain how to get `pdfopen`/`pdfclose` working for Adobe Reader XI? If you could make your instructions as detailed as possible that would be really appreciated. I'm using Miktex 2.9 on Windows 7.

Tex editor Winedt version 5.5

More information on problem:

If Adobe Reader (AR) is closed and I hit Pdf Texify button on Winedt
The program compiles and AR opens, however, immediately the file Acrobat OpenDoc.edt opens in Winedt editor and the following message pops up:

> Cannot Open DDE link to:
>   "C:\Program Files (x86) \Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.edx"
>   Service: Acroview
>   Topic:control
>   DDEOpen(‘%$(“AcroRead”)’,”acroview”,”control”,0);

If I want to compile my tex file again, I need to first manually close AR.

I thought it might be connected to the problem described here:
http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2190/

but I don't know how to implement what is suggested.

Comment: This is usually an editor feature, could you please provide it's name?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean closing the file automatically because Adobe locks the file for overwriting? If so use Sumatra PDF.

Comment: See http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2190/

Comment: have you seen [TeXnicCenter & Adobe Acrobat 10](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43864)?

Comment: Apologies for lack of detail. I'm using Winedt Build: 20071003 (v. 5.5). Hope this helps.

Comment: You should update to version 7. Version 5.5 of WinEdt is rather old ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name of the DDE server for version Adobe Reader XI (i.e. version 11) must be `AcroViewR11`, cf. [Big Changes in the DDE Naming Convention for Acrobat X](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/2011/01/big-changes-in-the-dde-naming-convention-for-acrobat-x.html). According to the error message you still use `acroview`.

In the blog entry you can also read, that for Adobe Acrobat XI the DDE server would be `AcroViewA11`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but could you help me with the specific tasks I need to perform? Is this a change this is required in Miktex or Winedt? I'm a complete novice.

Comment: @Neil: It has nothing to do with miktex. It is the editor (winedt) which tries to tell the pdf reader to open (or close) a pdf. Every new reader version changes the names (and sometimes the commands) needed and the author of winedt has a hard time to get things working again. There has been a message on the winedt mailing list about what to do in winedt 7 some days ago. I suggest that you ask there what to do in winedt 5.5 (if you want to keep it and if you don't want to use sumatra).

Answer (score 6):

For those of you that are still using the Adobe Reader as a previewer with
WinEdt 7 (rather than the more suitable application for this task:
SumatraPDF) and are considering upgrading to AR 11 here is what
you should know.

The AR 11 installer "forgets" to update the registry with the new
DDE Service (in fact it puts old AcroViewR10). Consequently WinEdt
will not be able to perform forward search or close the file that
is being locked by AR before it is recompiled. You can read more
about it on:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4792194

or google for more (it affects all applications that rely on DDE
service with Adobe)...

A solution (if you still insist on using AR): In WinEdt start
Options Interface. In Advanced branch open PDF Macros and
double-click on Adobe Blues. At the end you will find something
like:

```
// If you must manually modify any of these variables do it here:
//
// Assign(!"PDF-Caption",!"Adobe Reader");
// Assign(!"Acro-DDE_Topic",!"Control");
// Assign(!"Acro-DDE_Service",!"AcroviewR11");
```

Remove the comment in the last line and execute the macro
(`Ctrl+F9`). If you have full Acrobat (rather than a free reader)
then the service is probably AcroviewA11 or else just Acroview for
Acrobat Pro (try a few values until it works for your version).

And remember these instructions for the next Adobe version...

Answer (score 3):

I just tested it with WinEdt 7.0. It runs without changes after the installation of Reader XI.

I do not know the menu of WinEdt 5.5, but under WinEdt 7.0 you can choose `Options` -> `Execution Modes`-> `PDF Viewer`. There you can add 4 different pdf viewers. Choose one and search the path for your Acrobat reader. Activate it with clicking on `Alternative Reader x` and `Apply`.  Afterwards I was able to display a pdf file with Acrobat Reader XI.

[image: Configuration of pdf Viewer in WinEdt 7.0]

Answer (score 3):

I changed `"acroview"` to `"AcroviewR11"` in the file `Acrobat CloseDoc.edt` and it worked after that. The line now reads:   `DDEOpen('%$("AcroRead")',"AcroviewR11","control"`);

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using WinEdt (v. 5.4) and Adobe Professional 8 and I fixed my problem using [this method](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.editors.winedt/1677/match=finally+successfully+uncommented+iflocked+line+macro+acrobat+closedoc+edt+now+reader+closes+updates+properly+placed+my+application+data+winedt+exec+folder). For completeness, here's an extract of the discussion:

```
From: <wkehowski <at> cox.net>
Subject: Acrobat Reader 7.0 problem
Newsgroups: gmane.editors.winedt
Date: 2005-12-02 15:31:08 GMT (7 years, 8 weeks, 9 hours and 32 minutes ago)
Hello,

I finally successfully uncommented the IfLocked line in the macro Acrobat CloseDoc.edt and now Reader
closes and updates properly. I placed the macro in my Application Data/WinEdt/Exec folder. 

Thanks for your help, Alex. Rock on!

Here's the edited macro:

// -*- ASCII:EDT -*-
// Acrobat: Close PDF Document ...
//  Full description of all DDE Functions implemented by Acrobat (only
//  some are also supported by Acrobat Reader as indicated for each one):
//
//   https://partners.adobe.com/asn/acrobat/sdk/reg/Documentation/Core_API/CoreAPIReference.pdf

Requires(20040114); // Requires this build of WinEdt to work properly
// Close the current Document in Acrobat (Reader) using DDE

     IfOK(>
       !*>
         ProcessMessages;>
         DDEOpen("%$(""AcroRead"")","acroview","control");>
// A bug in Adobe: if another application (eg. TeXify) started it with 8.3 filename
// WinEdt has to use 8.3 filename as well or else Adobe will not close the document!
// Nothing WinEdt can do about this (8.3 filenames are obsolete anyway)...
//         DDEExe("[DocOpen(""%~P\%~N.pdf"")]");  // Has to be Opened via DDE DocOpen<>
//         DDEExe("[DocClose(""%~P\%~N.pdf"")]"); // for DocClose to work...<>
//         DDEExe("[CloseAllDocs()]"); // A bit too radical <>
         DDEExe("[DocOpen(""%P\%N.pdf"")]");  // Has to be Opened via DDE DocOpen<>
         DDEExe("[DocClose(""%P\%N.pdf"")]"); // for DocClose to work...<>
         DDEClose;>
         // Sync problem - wait until the file is released:<>
         // Acrobat Reader may take some time to release the pdf file!<>
         StartWorking('Closing PDF Document...');>
         SendMessage("%$(`Acro-Title`);", $0000, $0000);>
         ProcessMessages;>
         LetRegNum(0,0);>
         Loop( // Prevent an Infinite Loop: 5 sec. max<>
           !|LetRegNum(0,%!0+1);IfNum(%!0,55,'>','Stop;');>
             IfFileLocked("%P\%N.pdf", 00110,!'ProcessMessages;Wait(99);',!'Stop;',!'Stop;');>
            |);>
         SetFocus;>
         ProcessMessages;>
         StopWorking;>
         //Prompt('Required Iterations: %!0.'); // Testing for Problems<>
        *);

End;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem with WinEdt 10.2. To find out the right command name to use (to be put in `Options->Execution modes->PDF Viewer->Adobe DDE Service Blues`), check the following registry key:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\acrobat\shell\open\ddeexec\application]
```

In my case it was "AcroViewA18". After adding the registry value WinEdt seems able to interact (open/close) with Acrobat without problems.

Hope this helps future users!

Answer (score -1):

go to C:\Program Files (x86)\WinEdt Team\WinEdt\Exec ther is four file colled close and open try to find DDEOpen('%$("AcroRead");',"acroviewsR10","control"); change to DDEOpen('%$("AcroRead");',"acroviewsR11","control");
then the problem will be solved

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score -1):

hash out the entire portion, that solved is problem.

```
  //DDEOpen('%$("AcroRead")',"acroview","control",0);
  //DDEExe('[FileOpen("%P\%N.pdf")]');
  //DDEExe('[DocOpen("%P\%N.pdf")]');
  //DDEExe('[DocOpen("%P\%N.pdf")]');
  //DDEExe('[FileOpen("%P\%N.pdf")]');
  //DDEExe('[AppShow()]');
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).