# Unable to use pdftex if Adobe is still open

Tags: pdftex, windows, viewers, adobe

I'm sorry if this exact question has already been asked, but the similar duplicates I've found didn't have the same phrasing. Therefore, I'm asking a new question...

I have WinEdt 7.0 on Windows 7 and I have Adobe Acrobat Pro 9.0. Whenever I open WinEdt and I compile a file, everything works like a charm. If I re-compile without closing Adobe, the compiling fails and I get an error:

> Cannot Open DDE Link to:
>
> "C:\Progam Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"
>
> Service: AcroviewA11
>
> Topic: Control
>
> DDEOpen("%$('PDF-View')","%$('Acro-DDE_Service);",...

All of the problems I've found on the site have been related to changing `acroview` to `acroviewA11`, but I wasn't able to find these anywhere.

Can someone help me?

**UPDATE:** Since I can't post answers for another 6 hours, and I have a high probability of forgetting to return here and accept an answer, I'll post my exact actions here.

After going to `Options Interface->Advanced Configuration->PDF Macros->Adobe Blues`, and making the recommended changes from `AcroviewA11` to `Acroview` according to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85867/pdfopen-pdfclose-dont-work-with-acrobat-adobe-reader-xi/93974#93974) answer, I executed the macro by going to `Macros->Execute Current Macro` (or it can be done using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>). At this point, I checked and it worked! The error occurred because I run Adobe 9 and not Adobe 11; however, I'm not sure what the precise cause of it was.

Comment: The problem is probably that Reader locks the PDF for editing, so `pdftex` cannot change it. You could try [Sumatra](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) instead, this will auto-update the PDF if it changed.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) the answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73817/6621 may be useful

Comment: I don't think I will mind switching PDF viewers, but I'm rather ignorant as to how I should change the WinEdt settings for a default viewer. And, I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the problem is relatively new. I installed an update for Adobe, perhaps 3 days ago (who knows how old the update was, though), and that was what started the error messages.

Comment: @cmhughes: I began reading with high hopes, but (at least according to the directions of that answer) my Adobe doesn't have a Protected Mode option. I went as far as to go to the help menu and perform a search query for "Protected Mode" with 0 results, and then I reduced the query to "Protected" with only 3 results, all of them unrelated.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I hadn't tagged you earlier because I assumed you would revisit and check on the status of my question. At any rate, the Adobe Acrobat I have doesn't have an option for Protected Mode (see previous comments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with Acrobat is that they changed the naming convention for DDE commands. For the version 11 you have to use `AcroviewA11`, for version 9 and before it was and has to be `Acroview`.

In question [pdfopen-pdfclose](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85867/pdfopen-pdfclose-dont-work-with-acrobat-adobe-reader-xi/93974#93974) user @user24452 showed how to do this. My answer showed how you can integrate also SumatraPDF into WinEdt.

As you wrote in your comment, after changing `AcroviewA11` to `Acroview` use Ctrl+Shift+F9.

Comment: +1 for taking the time and helping me! I wish I could upvote twice, you've earned it :)