# MiKTeX, TeXnicCenter: can't show PDF file

Tags: miktex, viewers, texniccenter, adobe

I've got a problem with my pdf output.

When I click the button to create and show the **active** document I get the alert

```
[DocOpen("%bm.pdf")][FileOpen(%bm.pdf")].
```

I wonder why, because only creating the file works fine and when it is created I can watch the pdf. It even does work if I use the simple create and show **without "active"**. But the **"active"** document makes problems. I don't have any warnings or failures at creating the document.

Another thing is that it already worked and suddenly stopped working. I did not change any settings neither updated Acrobat Reader 11.

Summed up: Create and show **active** document does not work while create and show document works fine. My Document does not has any problems.

My settings look like [this](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-18886461/Unbenannt.png.html)!

Sorry if this is a double post, but I did not find any answers relating to my specific problem. The Answers I found where related to problems, when it never worked before and to Acrobat Reader 10.

Hope my question is clear ;)

Comment: You must change the name of Adobe’s DDE server, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77904/9237.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you comment. I got some help when I navigated to another link at the post you linked here first. And I opend the link of you second comment and there is an answer to my problem too. But I think the problem was another. So same answer different question :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `%bm` to `%tm`. There has been a change in MiKTeX from version 2.8 to 2.9 with the result, that in special cases `%bm` is not longer working. For me everything runs well after that changings.

Comment: Thanks you very much. This works fine and helped a lot! :D

Comment: Where should I make this change?

Comment: @littleO try build->define output profiles in TexnicCenter menu.